# What does this symbol mean in Java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I was looking through some example code from the elasticsearch library and I noticed these symbols:

```
        java.lang.Short.class.getName(), "[S", "[[S", "[[[S",
        java.lang.Character.class.getName(), "[C", "[[C", "[[[C",
        java.lang.Byte.class.getName(), "[B", "[[B", "[[[B",
        java.lang.Boolean.class.getName(), "[Z", "[[Z", "[[[Z",
```

What do they mean? They are only noted next to the primitive datatype objects.

Comment: They are binary names of primitive array types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its class names for array. Try

```
System.out.println(new short[1].getClass());
System.out.println(new short[1][1].getClass());
System.out.println(new int[1].getClass());
System.out.println(new char[1].getClass());
```